# Where can I find database backup files?

Tags: backup, database, phpmyadmin

Is it possible to find a database backup within phpMyadmin or are backup files always stored locally on a pc?

Comment: PhpMyadmin is just a program your backup is on the pc

Answer (score 2):

phpMyAdmin does not create backups for you – unless you set up some backups yourself, there are no backups stored *within* phpMyAdmin nor on your local drive.

If you wanted backups, you would have (had) to either backup the MySQL storage files themselves, or create scheduled SQL exports from your databases.

Windows' or your Linux distribution's built-in backup methods would automatically backup those MySQL data files if you included their location. [AutoMySQLBackup](https://sourceforge.net/projects/automysqlbackup/) is a script for Linux that creates SQL exports on a regular basis.

Comment: Thank you. Quick follow-up question. In the recent past, Godaddy has made independent backups of my database. When I need to roll back, they will do a restore for a fee. I have learned that if I find the copy that they have made myself, I can run the backup for free. Do other hosting providers typically operate in the same way?

Comment: I unfortunately don't have a lot of experience with hosting providers. But I'd assume that they would store your backups somewhere else, on a completely different system, where they would not be accessible to you. For two reasons: (1) If they can charge for it, why should they give you access to the files? (Although they could allow you to download the files, after all, the restoring itself is what's time-consuming.) (2) If you store the backups close to the real data, they're worth nothing in case of broken filesystems, hard drives, or even intrusions by hackers.

Comment: Glad I could help. If that post answered your question, you can mark it as accepted using the green checkbox next to it.